# Visualizing Laplace Transform

Tags: linear-transformations, laplace-transform, visualization

I watched Linear algebra series on 3Blue1Brown channel, This blow my mind, I loved it and now I can visualize Linear transformation works. But what about Laplace transform, it is also a linear transform. Is there any way you can visualize it as one does in matrix? Choosing basis and so on?

Comment: It's a differential operator. How can we visualize an operator on a *function space*?

Comment: You may find [this blog post](https://johnflux.com/2019/02/12/laplace-transform-visualized/) interesting, which attempts to animate the Laplace transform of various functions.